# EWS FindItem call returns incorrect EffectiveRights values

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I'm using a FindItem call to get items (appointments) from Exchange Web Services (EWS). The properties which are fetched are the item Id and the EffectiveRights. The EffectiveRights property often does not contain the correct values. Sometimes, however, the values are correct (using the same code), but I don't know what causes this.

The Calendar folder I'm searching in is delegated with Author rights to the service user I authenticate with and it contains appointments of which this service user is the author of.

I'm using the [ews-java-api](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api) library and the response traces show that this isn't a parsing bug.

The code used to retrieve the items:

```java
ItemView view = new ItemView(100);
PropertySet propertySet = new PropertySet();
propertySet.add(ItemSchema.Id);
propertySet.add(ItemSchema.EffectiveRights);
view.setPropertySet(propertySet);

FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, Mailbox.getMailboxFromString(targetSmtpAddress));
FindItemsResults<Item> items = service.findItems(folderId, filter, view);

Item firstItem = items.getItems().get(0);
firstItem.getEffectiveRights(); // Returns NONE, READ. This is incorrect.

Item bindItem = Item.bind(service, firstItem.getId()); // 
bindItem.getEffectiveRights(); // Returns NONE, READ, MODIFY, DELETE. This is correct.
```

The request trace:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2"></t:RequestServerVersion>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                <t:AdditionalProperties>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:ItemId"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:EffectiveRights"></t:FieldURI>
                </t:AdditionalProperties>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:IndexedPageItemView MaxEntriesReturned="1000" Offset="0" BasePoint="Beginning"></m:IndexedPageItemView>
            <m:Restriction>
                <t:And>
                    <t:IsEqualTo>
                        <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="039b4d91-2f03-44da-887c-aad704243ba8" PropertyName="SyncId" PropertyType="String"></t:ExtendedFieldURI>
                        <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
                            <t:Constant Value="syncID:330"></t:Constant>
                        </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
                    </t:IsEqualTo>
                    <t:IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                        <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start"></t:FieldURI>
                        <t:FieldURIOrConstant>
                            <t:Constant Value="2015-01-28T13:53:38Z"></t:Constant>
                        </t:FieldURIOrConstant>
                    </t:IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo>
                </t:And>
            </m:Restriction>
            <m:ParentFolderIds>
                <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar">
                    <t:Mailbox>
                        <t:EmailAddress>TARGETUSER@SMTP.ADDRESS</t:EmailAddress>
                    </t:Mailbox>
                </t:DistinguishedFolderId>
            </m:ParentFolderIds>
        </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

The trace of a 'faulty' response:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="224" MinorBuildNumber="2" Version="Exchange2010_SP2" xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <m:FindItemResponse xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
            <m:ResponseMessages>
                <m:FindItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
                    <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
                    <m:RootFolder IndexedPagingOffset="1000" TotalItemsInView="1868" IncludesLastItemInRange="false">
                        <t:Items>
                            <t:CalendarItem>
                                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGVlZmVlY2JjLTcxOTItNDBkYi1hOTljLTkwZjQwZjE4MTU1NQBGAAAAAADZ8IosQv76QbxS0r8FeFzgBwB25IsPmJcKTaP6zvCUqaybAAAAoIe5AAB25IsPmJcKTaP6zvCUqaybAABcSsgnAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAB25IsPmJcKTaP6zvCUqaybAABcS6ER"/>
                                <t:EffectiveRights>
                                    <t:CreateAssociated>false</t:CreateAssociated>
                                    <t:CreateContents>false</t:CreateContents>
                                    <t:CreateHierarchy>false</t:CreateHierarchy>
                                    <t:Delete>false</t:Delete>
                                    <t:Modify>false</t:Modify>
                                    <t:Read>true</t:Read>
                                    <t:ViewPrivateItems>false</t:ViewPrivateItems>
                                </t:EffectiveRights>
                            </t:CalendarItem>
                            <t:CalendarItem>
                                <t:ItemId Id="AAMkAGVlZmVlY2JjLTcxOTItNDBkYi1hOTljLTkwZjQwZjE4MTU1NQBGAAAAAADZ8IosQv76QbxS0r8FeFzgBwB25IsPmJcKTaP6zvCUqaybAAAAoIe5AAB25IsPmJcKTaP6zvCUqaybAABcSsglAAA=" ChangeKey="DwAAABYAAAB25IsPmJcKTaP6zvCUqaybAABcS6EN"/>
                                <t:EffectiveRights>
                                    <t:CreateAssociated>false</t:CreateAssociated>
                                    <t:CreateContents>false</t:CreateContents>
                                    <t:CreateHierarchy>false</t:CreateHierarchy>
                                    <t:Delete>false</t:Delete>
                                    <t:Modify>false</t:Modify>
                                    <t:Read>true</t:Read>
                                    <t:ViewPrivateItems>false</t:ViewPrivateItems>
                                </t:EffectiveRights>
                            </t:CalendarItem>

                            <!-- MORE ITEMS HERE... -->

                        </t:Items>
                    </m:RootFolder>
                </m:FindItemResponseMessage>
            </m:ResponseMessages>
        </m:FindItemResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I already found [this blog post](http://www.networksteve.com/exchange/topic.php/ItemSchema.EffectiveRights_give_wrong_results/?TopicId=39422) which seems somewhat related, but nothing more than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FindItems loads values from the contents table of a folder, rather than from the items themselves. Many times, with computed properties like EffectiveRights, a simplistic approach is used to populate the table to give an approximation. It seems like that's what's happening here. The comment in your code mentions that the value is correct after you Bind to the item (which loads values from the item itself).

Comment: It's not the answer I hoped for, but at least I have an explanation now.